# Site Load Timer Tool To Demo Effectiveness

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, page-load-time

I am building a tool that speeds up site search by providing an ajax front-end and a cdn back-end.

I want to demonstrate visually in a demo the difference between using my ajax front end and the normal html re-load model.  I need a tool such as a browser extension or other tool that can show the **transition from one page on a site to another**.  There are gobs of tools that can show page load times.  That is not what I am after.  I want to show the transition from one ajax state to another ajax state.

Does anybody have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

As Andy mentioned, you can do this with [WebPagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/).  Don't get too put off by the "scripting", there are a fair number of samples and I'm happy to help with a specific case as well.

One of the cool things you can do with it is record the sequence as a video and have it create a side-by-side video so you can demonstrate the actual user experience (which always sells better than the metrics).

Answer (score 0):

> I need a tool such as a browser extension or other tool that can show
>   the transition from one page on a site to another.

I think the solution is to either make two separate pages and compare them side-by-side, with firebug (or a similar tool) open

Or you can make an actual presentation and perform a transition yourself. I don't know of a tool that merely presents a side-by-side comparison of two sites and their benchmarks, unless you count a powerpoint presentation or a whitepaper a "tool"

Also, you can do visual benchmarking of actual javascript code performance with JSPerf (http://jsperf.com/)

Answer (score 0):

WebPageTest can do this but you'll need to learn how to script it